# How do I make a puppet class dependent on all of the resources it defines?

Tags: puppet

I am working on a rather large and complicated puppet module, and I ran into an issue where declaring a dependency on a class does not translate to a dependency on class resources defined in that class.  I have created an example.

```
node default {
  notify {'This is my notification':
    require => Class['big_class'],
  }
  class {'big_class':}
}

class big_class {
  notify {'This is my big class':}
  class {'little_class':}
}

class little_class{
  notify {'This is my little class':}
  class {'smallest_class':}
}

class smallest_class {
  notify {'This is my smallest class':}
}
```

My desired behavior is for smallest, little, and big to all resolve before the notification.  But Puppet doesn't work this way. The result of the run is as follows:

```
Notice: This is my little class
Notice: /Stage[main]/Little_class/Notify[This is my little class]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is my little class'
Notice: This is my big class
Notice: /Stage[main]/Big_class/Notify[This is my big class]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is my big class'
Notice: This is my notification
Notice: /Stage[main]//Node[default]/Notify[This is my notification]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is my notification'
Notice: This is my smallest class
Notice: /Stage[main]/Smallest_class/Notify[This is my smallest class]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is my smallest class'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds
```

The smallest class resolved after the 'This is my notification' even though it is defined effectively 'within' a requirement on the notification.  What is the best practice for handling this type of senario?  If this is the desired behavior, is there a way to declare that resources defined within a class are requirements of that class?  Do all of the resources inside of `class class_name` need to have a meta-parameter `before => Class['class_name'],`?

Edit: The following results in puppet complaining about dependency cycles.

```
class smallest_class {
  notify {'This is my smallest class':
    before => Class['smallest_class'],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, generating a dot [graph](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/faq.html#how-do-i-use-puppets-graphing-support) over your manifest, we can see there are no actual dependencies between classes.

There are a few options to address this.

1. Create precise dependencies within the classes between the notify statements (non-ideal).
2. Use [run stages](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_run_stages.html)
3. Use puppetlabs-stdlib [anchor](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Anchor_Pattern) pattern
4. If running puppet >= 3.4, they have a new [contain](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_containment.html) function